# Flush ListView every 4 week. The timer should no reset even if rebooted.

Tags: android, timer, alarmmanager, counter

I have a requirement to flush my list view every 4 week. Now the question is what is the ideal solution to do this ?

```
1) AlarmManager
2) Counter
3) Timer
```

The condition is the time should no reset on reboot, it should save and continue the same when it was installed and timer started.

For example : If i install today. The timer should flush my listview after 4 week. Even if i reboot in between, the timer should not be recreated. It should only flush listview after the 4 week when application installed.

What could be the ideal solution for this ?

I tried AlarmManager and it restarts on reboot.

Comment: save the time in the preference every time you quit the app. Read it when the app starts and calculate the time elapsed.

Comment: @AmulyaKhare : Do u suggest AlarmManager to do that ? Any example u have ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can  do  here is save the time when you want to flush the `ListView` using preferences or sqlite database. Then register a `BroadcastReceiver` for device restart broadcast action. When you receive this action, you can again use `AlarmManager` to set the alarm for the time that you have previously saved in your preference or sqlite.

If you are confused when to save the time in preference or sqlite you can either do it when the `ListView` is flushed or your can register for device shutdown action and then can trigger the code to save the time in your `BroadcastReceiver`.